# RequireJs - seems to be reusing the same object when returning a `new function()`

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am using requireJs for dependency management.

address.js

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {

    //private fields
    var $name = null;
    var $number = null;
    var $street = null;
    var $suburb = null;

    var initialisationAttempts = 0;

    return new function() {

        //public fields


        /**
         * initialise for first use
         */
        this.init = function(fields) {
            if(initialisationAttempts > 0) {
                console.log('ERROR: Address has been initialised (' + ++initialisationAttempts + ') times!');
            } else {
                $name = fields.$name;
                $number = fields.$number;
                $street = fields.$street;
                $suburb = fields.$suburb;

                initialisationAttempts++;
            }
        };

        /**
         * Clean all form fields
         */
        this.clear = function () {
            $name.val('');
            $number.val('');
            $street.val('');
            $suburb.val('');
        };

    };
});
```

I have two different implementation of the address

fromAddress.js

```
define(['page/lib/address', 'jquery'], function(address, $) {

    fromFields = {
        $name: $("#from-address-name"),
        $number: $("#from-address-number"),
        $street: $("#from-address-street"),
        $suburb: $("#from-address-suburb"),
    };

    address.init(fromFields);

    return address;
});
```

toAddress.js

```
define(['page/lib/address', 'jquery'], function(address, $) {

    fromFields = {
        $name: $("#to-address-name"),
        $number: $("#to-address-number"),
        $street: $("#to-address-street"),
        $suburb: $("#to-address-suburb"),
    };

    address.init(fromFields);

    return address;
});
```

If I call these is sequence

```
(function() {

    require(['jquery', 'page/lib/fromAddress', 'page/lib/toAddress'], function ($, fromAddress, toAddress) {

        $(document).ready( function() {

            //clear all input fields
                fromAddress.clear();
                toAddress.clear();

        });

    });

})();
```

The call to `toAddress.clear()` cannot run the `init` function because it has already been called by the `fromAddress` object (I get the 'ERROR' message in the `init` method).  I want the toAddress and fromAddress objects to refer to different address objects, how can I achieve this?

### UPDATE:

As per the suggestions, I have modified the code as below and it seems to be working.

address.js

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {

    return function(fields) {

        //public fields

        /**
         * Clean all form fields
         */
        this.clear = function () {
            fields.$name.val('');
            fields.$number.val('');
            fields.$street.val('');
            fields.$suburb.val('');

            fields.$suburb.css("background-color", fields.colour);
        };

    };
});
```

fromAddress.js

```
define(['jquery', 'page/lib/address'], function(jq, address) {

    fields= {
        $name: jq("#from-address-name"),
        $number: jq("#from-address-number"),
        $street: jq("#from-address-street"),
        $suburb: jq("#from-address-suburb"),
        colour: 'green',
    };

    return new address(fields);
});
```

toAddress.js

```
define(['jquery', 'page/lib/address'], function(jq, address) {

    fields= {
        $name: jq("#to-address-name"),
        $number: jq("#to-address-number"),
        $street: jq("#to-address-street"),
        $suburb: jq("#to-address-suburb"),
        colour: 'red',
    };

    return new address(fields);
});
```

Comment: Remove `new` from address.js (it's returning an object), and call `new address()` in toAddress.js and fromAddress.js. And you're creating a whole bunch of global variables.

Comment: That's what RequireJS does. It's very handy if you need singletons. If you want to get different objects each time, just return the function instread of `return new function`, and use the *new* operator on it in each of the dependent files.

Comment: @NagaJolokia, you said I was creating a whole bunch of global variables, can you explain where?

Comment: There was a display glitch in my browser and part of your code hadn't rendered. So it's no longer a bunch. But there's still `fromFields`.

Comment: @NagaJolokia, but isn't `fromFields` (or `fields` in the updated quesion) local to the `define` callback function?

Comment: `(function(){ foo = "bar"; }()); window.foo; // "bar"`